# How to change GridLayoutGroup 's item sprite at run time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid-layout

I'm implementing Inventory System for a Unity Game.Players have to pick only 3 items to pick from 18 inventory items(`GridLayoutGroup`).If the player click item,I want to change GridLayoutGroup item's sprite to checked image.How do I access GridLayoutGroup item at runtime.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Inside the GridLayoutGroup the items are still e.g. an `Image` component or maybe even a `Button` so can't you just put your code on the items to determine which one you clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

U can use [toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Toggle.html), it has 2 images: background and checkmark, the background image would be "non selected" and the checkmark - "Selected".